# Check kernel version in recipe

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Is there a way to make a recipe (in-)compatible to a certain kernel version? I'm thinking of a mechanism as provided by `COMPATIBLE_MACHINE` but for the kernel.
Or would that compatibility check need to be done inside one of the tasks?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it but maybe something like:

```
UNWANTED_KV = "xxx"

python __anonymous () {
    if d.getVar('KERNEL_VERSION') == d.getVar('UNWANTED_KV'):
        raise bb.parse.SkipRecipe("incompatible with %s kernel version" % d.getVar('KERNEL_VERSION'))
}
```